# How to get a JWT token from openAM

Tags: java, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, openam

We would like to get a JWT access token.
Indeed, when I call /openam/oauth2/access_token the default behavior of open am is to deliver an access_token that looks like “aaaaa-bbbb-ccccc-ddddd”

Thanks
Gyan

Answer (score 4):

OpenAM by default issues stateful OAuth2 access tokens, where the format of the access token is essentially UUID.

In order to issue OAuth2 access tokens in JWT format you must turn on the Stateless OAuth2 feature in the OAuth2 provider settings (only supported since 13.5.0).

Comment: It would be helpful to provide steps or link to documentation on turning on the stateless token feature. After enabling stateless tokens at the realm level and at the global level, the token is still coming as a UUID on OpenAM 14.6.2. Turning it on at the global level required using `ssoadm` since the XUI was experiencing a bug when trying to change any OAuth2 Provider settings.